# access 2010 custom ribbon

Tags: vba, ms-access, ribbon

I have a custom ribbon that calls vba commands. When it does, I get the error message

```
Microsoft Access cannot run the macro or callback function [FUNCTION OR SUB]
```

where `[FUNCTION OR SUB]` is the Function or Sub name I am calling.

An example of the code that generates the above message is:

```
Public Function OnButtonPress2(ctl As IRibbonControl)

    MsgBox "OnButtonPress2"

End Function
```

Where `OnButtonPress2` is called in the ribbon's XML file for a button as

`onAction="OnButtonPress2`

The above works for a macro, so it's likely not to be the ribbon's xml

======== VERSION 2
I've created a new simple test db with the XML and module shown below:

The results of each are:

Macro1 - works fine (it has a popup message)

CommandOnAction2 - msgbox "There was an error compiling this function"

OnButtonPress2 - msgbox  "Microsoft Access cannot run the macro or callback function 'OnButtonPress2 '

on the line "Public gobjRibn As IRibbonUI", IRibbonUI does not autocomplete leading me to believe there is a reference that needs to be added

**XML (Ribbon name is NewRibbon and is set to open on startup)**

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
<tabs>
<tab id="tab1" label="Your Custom Tab">

<group id="group1" label="Your Custom Group">
<button id="SampleButton" label="Macro1" onAction="Macro1" />
<button id="SampleButton2" label="CommandOnAction2" onAction="=CommandOnAction2()"  />
<button id="SampleButton3" label="OnButtonPress2" onAction="OnButtonPress2"  />
</group>
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

**module (name is modRibbon)**

```
Option Compare Database

Public gobjRibn As IRibbonUI

Public Function CommandOnAction2(ByVal ctl As IRibbonControl)
    MsgBox "Function CommandOnAction2"
End Function

Public Sub OnButtonPress2(ByVal ctl As IRibbonControl)
    MsgBox " Sub OnButtonPress2"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate your issue in Access 2010 and I got your example to work by changing the `Function` to a `Sub` that looks like this:

```
Public Sub OnButtonPress2(ByVal control_ As IRibbonControl)
    MsgBox "OnButtonPress2"
End Sub
```

BTW, while searching for information on this issue I stumbled upon a posting in another forum [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/4e8751a1-b6aa-4837-a1e2-1711b25f0567). In it, Albert D. Kallal discusses using `onAction="=MyPublicFunctionName()"` as an alternative to callbacks; perhaps you may find that useful in some cases.

Comment: Gord, thank you, I am still having the same issue, I've added a new example above under ====VERSION 2 with results.  One problem that may be critical is that IRibbonUI in the declarations will not autocomplete after 'Public gobjRibn As' - I may have a missing reference but don't know what it should be.

Comment: You need to reference the MSO.DLL. For example, on a 64-bit machine with a 32-bit Office 2010 (=Office 14): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\MSO.DLL